# How to get the button result of New or Quit message dialog?

Tags: python

Is there any way to get the button result of `New` or `Quit` message dialog?

If blender file `bpy.data.is_dirty == True`, the message in the image below appears when `bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile()` or `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()`.

So, I want to get the result of clicking a button in the message `Save`, `Don't Save` or `Cancel`.

I'm able to change the string of messages in file `source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_files.c`, but I couldn't get the resulting key or flag.

```
static void wm_block_file_close_cancel_button();
static void wm_block_file_close_discard_button();
static void wm_block_file_close_save_button();
```

[image: Quit_Dialog]

Comment: Hello ! Do you mean that you want to open a popup dialog with custom button labels, or that you want to invoke this specific dialog popup with your code ?

Comment: @Gorgious No, I mean I want to get a click result of this popup dialog. I already checked button message in theire function, but I can't get the click result of each button. If I click a `Don't Save` button, then I want to get the `Don't Save` key of flag value in bpy or anywhere. Can I do this?

Comment: So you want to bypass this popup dialog ? Directly quit without saving the file ?

Comment: @Gorgious Bypass and different actions for each button. I want to perform different actions according to the result of 3 buttons. For example, If I click `Save` button, I want to draw cube after file save. Or if I click `Don't Save` button, I will draw sphere after `read_homefile()`. Cancel also wants to perform another action. Can I do this?